# WordPress database error Table on local wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i see this when I run php -S localhost:3303 to see my local wordpress site

```
WordPress database error Table 'imgprep_wp.wp_wfConfig' doesn't exist for query SELECT name, val, autoload FROM wp_wfConfig WHERE name = 'allowLegacy2FA' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), include_once('/plugins/wordfence/wordfence.php'), require_once('/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php'), wfCredentialsController::useLegacy2FA, wfCredentialsController::allowLegacy2FA, wfConfig::get
```

Comment: This is a semi-common problem related to WordFence, and they have a separate plugin that you can try to install to fix it. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence-assistant/

Comment: thx I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

There was a plugin in our local environment that was causing issues when running updates for other plugins (strange, right?).

To solve I had to disable **WP Offload Media** on local and then the plugin update for WordFence runs as expected.